Simple plot in Orange
I'm trying to create a line plot. I must be missing something simple... just not sure what. I've done several guide and tutorials that worked great with the provided sample data. Now that I'm trying to use my data I'm stuck with an empty graph.



Unix
Unit
tValue
cValue




1.72757e+09
458.0
482
617


1.72757e+09
458.0
481
616


1.72761e+09
458.0
490
633


1.7276e+09
458.0
484
621


1.7276e+09
458.0
488
628


1.72761e+09
458.0
489
630


1.72758e+09
458.0
481
615


1.72758e+09
458.0
480
616


1.72758e+09
458.0
480
616



Unix timestamps can and will be duplicated for each unit in the input.
How do I create a line graph with the values from tValue and cValue?
The hard part is I don't know what I don't know. So formulating a question is... messy. ;) Any hits would be appreciated.


